# How to create a docker bind mount / volume with spaces in the path

Tags: docker

I want to create a bind mount, but my source path **has spaces in it** and because of that I can't create the bind mount because my command is not parsed correctly by docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple. **Just put quotes**

You can use either the "-v" flag or the "--mount" flag.

**With -v flag**

```
docker run -d -v "/mnt/c/Users/myUser/Name With Spaces/name":/app imageName
```

**With --mount flag**

```
docker run -d --mount src="/mnt/c/Users/myUser/Name With Spaces/name",target=/app,type=bind imageName
```

When using the mount flag be careful that you **DON'T add spaces between the keys** (target, src and type). For example this would be wrong and would not work (added space before target key):

```
docker run -d --mount src="/mnt/c/Users/myUser/Some Name With Spaces", target=/app,type=bind imageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding the $(pwd) with quotes worked for me.

```
docker run -d -v "$(pwd)":/app imageName
```

Comment: Hi, you are repeating the previous answer... Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)